# Squares from user input

Tags: python-3.x, input

I have to make a program that reads the user number from 1 to 100 and then presents all the squares of that number, somehow its always erroring

```
import math
numUser = int(input("Enter a value between 1 and 100: "))
counter = 1
if numUser >= 100 or numUser =< 0:
    print("Enter a valid number!")
else:
    while counter =< 100:
        squares = pow(numUser, 2)
```

Comment: Please edit the question and paste in the error message.

Comment: SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Comment: >then presents all the squares of that number - what exactly do you mean here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `=<` to `<=`. Also, the `counter` value never changes. This will be an infinite loop. Also, how will the squares be shown?

I am not sure of the value of calculating the same square 100 times. What does "all the squares of that number..." mean?

```
import math
numUser = int(input("Enter a value between 1 and 100: "))
counter = 1
if numUser >= 100 or numUser <= 0:
    print("Enter a valid number!")
else:
    while counter <= 100:
        squares = pow(numUser, 2)
        counter += 1
```

Comment: What's with the downvote? Please tell me so that I can do better.

Comment: dont know who downvoted
i forgot to add the print(numUser)
by all the squares of the number i meant all the values of the number squared between 1-100 forgot to mention sorry